# Counting occurrences in a Python list

Tags: python

I have a list of integers; for example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

I am trying to make a list of the three elements in `l` with the highest number of occurrences, in descending order of frequency. So in this case I want the list `[1, 4, 2]`, because `1` occurs the most in `l` (four times), `4` is next with three instances, and then `2` with two. I only want the top three results, so `3` (with only one instance) doesn't make the list.

How can I generate that list?

Answer (score 19):

Use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
l= [1 ,2 ,3 ,4,4,4 , 1 ,1 ,1 ,2]

x=collections.Counter(l)
print(x.most_common())
# [(1, 4), (4, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]

print([elt for elt,count in x.most_common(3)])
# [1, 4, 2]
```

`collections.Counter` was introduced in Python 2.7. If  you are using an older version, then you could use [the implementation here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Comment: Wow, python keeps having already implemented whatever you need. I'll just note that you do need a sufficiently new version of python for this to work. If you are running 2.6, you don't yet have Counter.

Answer (score 8):

```
l_items = set(l) # produce the items without duplicates
l_counts = [ (l.count(x), x) for x in set(l)]
# for every item create a tuple with the number of times the item appears and
# the item itself
l_counts.sort(reverse=True)
# sort the list of items, reversing is so that big items are first
l_result = [ y for x,y in l_counts ]
# get rid of the counts leaving just the items
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
l= [1 ,2 ,3 ,4,4,4 , 1 , 1 ,1 ,2]
counter=defaultdict(int)
for item in l:
    counter[item]+=1

inverted_dict = dict([[v,k] for k,v in counter.items()])

for count in sorted(inverted_dict.keys()):
    print inverted_dict[count],count
```

This should print out the most frequents items in 'l': you would need to restrict to the first three. Be careful when using the inverted_dict there (that is the keys and values gets swapped): this will result in an over-write of values (if two items have identical counts, then only one will be written back to the dict).

Answer (score 1):

Without using collections:

```
a = reversed(sorted(l,key=l.count))
outlist = []
for element in a:
  if element not in outlist:
    outlist.append(element)
```

The first line gets you all the original items sorted by count.

The for loop is necessary to uniquify without losing the order (there may be a better way).

Comment: `key=l.count` is nasty: it means you do n squared passes through the entire list (for every element count the number of occurrences of that element). Much better to use one of the `collection.Counter` or similar solutions that use a single pass to generate the counts.

Comment: @Duncan true, I hadn't thought of the complexity! Thanks for pointing that out.