# How to count the frequency of element of list of random integers?

Tags: python

```
def random_integers(lb, ub, trials):
    ri = []
    for i in range(trials):
        ri.insert(i, randint(lb, ub))
    return ri
```

This function creates the list of random integers. (Range of the integers: lb <= the integers <= ub, Length of the integers: trials)
What I want to do is count the frequency of elements of list that created by this function.
Ex) [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 0), (5,1)] for [1,2,3,5] So I wrote this code:

```
def freq_integers(num_list):
    fi = []
    for i in range(ub - lb + 1)
        fi.insert(i, (lb + i, num_list.count(lb + i)))
    return fi
```

If lb, ub in this function is same as random_integers function, it will work well. But lb and ub is only vaild in random_integers function.
I should use one parameter(num_list) so I can't define function as freq_integers(lb, ub, num_list). And I can't use lb, ub as a global variable because random_integers function has a parameter for that.

## This problem is different from ([How to count the frequency of the elements in an unordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-an-unordered-list))

Because this problem has to count the freuquency of item that not in the list.
Ex) [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 0), (5,1)] for [1,2,3,5]: from this it should count 4 as 0 which is not in the list. + Other quesitons count the thing only in list. like [1,1,1,2,2] : 1 appears 3 times 2 appears 2times.My problem is [1,1,1,2,2] can be counted as 1 appears 3times 2 appears 2times 3 appears 0times because of the input "Range". In this case Range would be 1<=integers<=3, length was 5. I want to know if other solution exists that don't use lb and ub –

Comment: In my opinion the easiest way to achieve such behaviour is relying on the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-an-unordered-list

Comment: thank you but using counter method is not allowed...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046387/counting-occurrences-in-a-python-list. This is a common problem and has many implementations you can look for online

Comment: What's the point of *"counting"* something that is not in the list? If it is not in the list, you know its count is `0`... Also you say that you can't access `lb` and `ub` and only have `num_list` so that is not even possible

Comment: I edited the question more specific for your question. sorry English is not my first language.

Comment: This doesn't change my question. You are saying you can't use `lb` and `ub`. So you can only work with `num_list` which is the numbers **present**. You don't know what numbers to *"count"* as zero. But I don't understand how is that a problem. If you didn't count a number at all (it is not in `num_list`) then its count is `0`...

Comment: You just need to use a `Counter` (or just a regular dict if you are not allowed), and then just query the counts as `counter.get(num, 0)`. This way, if a number was not present, you will print `0`

Comment: how is that a problem.-It's simply because looks good,,,thanks anyway. I define lb = min(num_list) , ub = max(num_list) in the second function. It couldn't express the 0 in some cases but i should done this problem..

Comment: I think you overcomplicating but ok... Just use a dict and the `get` method

Answer (score 0):

convert list to set before counting

```
random_list = random_integers(lb, ub, trials)
union = set(random_list)
counting = {num:random_list.count(num) for num in union}
```