# How to create a dictionary out of a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have extracted a list of numbers from a word document to see which hour of a day gives us the most number of visits. I wanted to create a key number pair dictionary from the list of numbers.

These are the list of numbers with me

`['09', '18', '16', '15', '15', '14', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '10', '10', '10', '09', '07', '06', '04', '04', '04', '19', '17', '17', '16', '16', '16']`

and my output should look somewhat like this

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

I'm not quite able to figure out what to next.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting occurrences in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046387/counting-occurrences-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

l = ['09', '18', '16', '15', '15', '14', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '10',
     '10', '10', '09', '07', '06', '04', '04', '04', '19', '17', '17', '16', '16', '16']
result = Counter(l)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
Counter({'09': 2,
         '18': 1,
         '16': 4,
         '15': 2,
         '14': 1,
         '11': 6,
         '10': 3,
         '07': 1,
         '06': 1,
         '04': 3,
         '19': 1,
         '17': 2})
```

To get the `most common` element you can use:

```
most_common_element = result.most_common(1)[0] # prints `11`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     z = ['09', '18', '16', '15', '15', '14', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '10', '10', '10', '09', '07', '06', '04', '04', '04', '19', '17', '17', '16', '16', '16']
        # trans list to dict
        d = dict((int(i), z.count(i)) for i in z)
        # sort dict by key
        d = dict(sorted(d.items()))
        print(d)
        OUTPUT:
 {4: 3,
     6: 1,
     7: 1,
     9: 2,
     10: 3,
     11: 6,
     14: 1,
     15: 2,
     16: 4,
     17: 2,
     18: 1,
     19: 1}
```

This is what you want